# Conditional \end or \bye in TeX (plain-tex)

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

Can someone figure out a conditional `\end` or `\bye` in TeX-Code? (plain tex)

I want to put in several lines into a TeX-file, each ending with `\end` , to be compiled before the document is complete, to gain and see the "status quo" of the document, later to be finally compiled using the last stated `\end``command.

Example:

```
This is the end \end This is the other end \end This is the last end \end
```

The first and second `\end` command should be deactivated or deleted, as long as another `\end` command follows, only the third (or last) `\end` command shall be expanded or used.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to achieve. Why not using a different command, finishing with `\bye`?

Comment: @egreg What different command could this be? TeX finishes compiling when reaching the `\end` command, ignoring the rest of the file. I want to compile the file to its very end, ignoring every `\end` that occurs before the last one.

Comment: @M.Borck-Elsner What's the meaning of the occurrences of `\end` before the end of the file? In any case, in plain you really want `\bye`, surely?

Answer (score 12):

This works, so long as the file has no empty line at the very end.

```
\let\TeXend\end
\def\blurb{}
\everyeof{\blurb}
\def\end{\futurelet\next\checkend}
\def\checkend{%
  \ifx\next\blurb
    \csname TeXend\expandafter\endcsname
  \fi
}

This is the end \end This is the other end \end This is the last end \end
```

But it's error prone and, in my opinion, useless. Requires e-TeX.

However, I don't see any usefulness of this. I'd rather use

```
\def\END{}
%\let\END\bye % when you want to remove the final notes

The document text

This is the end \END
This is the other end \END
This is the last end \END

\bye
```

---

If you know in advance the number of `\end` commands to stop after, then it's fairly easy:

```
\newcount\ends
\def\END{\advance\ends-1 \ifnum\ends=0 \csname bye\expandafter\endcsname\fi}


\ends=3

ABC \END DEF \END GHI \END JKL \END MNO \END PQR \END STU \END
\bye
```

This will print

> ABC DEF GHI

TeX refuses to process the token `\bye` in skipped over text in a conditional, but it doesn't balk if it skips over `\csname bye\endcsname`. The `\expandafter` ensures that we don't end with an unfinished conditional, by expanding `\fi` before executing `\bye`.

Answer (score 1):

Example `example.tex`:

```
This \end is \end the \end
```

Compile with:

```
pdftex -jobname example "\let\TeXend\end\let\end\relax \input example \TeXend"
```

But I don't really see why would you want that.

Answer (score 0):

Will `\csname end\endcsname` do any good? Like, for example,

```
\def\temporalend{\csname end\endcsname}
%\def\temporalend{}

Section 1
\temporalend

Section 2
\bye
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In all honesty, your answer looks like a non-sense to me. Maybe it was meant as a comment to either the question or the egreg's answer?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I solved this with numeral conditions.

```
\newcount\ends
\newcount\lastends
\ends=0
\lastends=3
\def\myend{\advance\ends by 1 \ifnum\ends=\lastends \end \else \fi}
ABC \myend DEF \myend GHI \myend JKL \myend MNO \myend PQR \myend STU \myend
\bye
```

By giving a value to `\lastends`, the document is compiled at the point, `\ends` reaches the value of `\lastends` , finally it is forced to be compiled by reaching the `\bye` command . The command `\bye` does not work in the conditionals,  so I used `\end`.

Comment: You might have explained that you know in advance the number of `\end` commands to ignore.

Comment: @egreg You are right. Eventually, I might not know the number of `\end` commands to ignore, but this may lead to infinite loop. Any solutions?

Comment: I still don't know what's your aim.

Comment: @egreg As mentioned in the question, I want to append lines or paragraphs or whatever to a document, each ending with an `\end` command, to be compiled before the document is complete, to see the current output. For example, I want to use `echo "First argument \myend ">>test.tex` to add some lines to the document, to compile it and see the output. All this should happen without opening the .tex-file.